# Disabling certain items in a Ext.form.ComboBox

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox

I have an ExtJS 4 web application in which I have an Ext.form.ComboBox in which I need to disable certain items from being selectable.

Yep, I know I can just filter those items in the combobox's store - but in this case I actually do want the user to see these non-selectable items - I just don't want them to be able to select them.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `beforeselect` event to cancel the selection, and the `itemTpl` so the disabled items look disabled, like:

```
listConfig: {
    itemTpl: '<div {[values.disabled ? \'class="disabled"\' : \'\']}>{value}</div>'
},
listeners: {
    beforeselect: function(cmp, record){
        return !record.get('disabled');
    }
}
```

Working example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/v4t